# window.location doesn't reload with params

Tags: javascript, hash, parameters, routes, window.location

I'm replacing window.location with params here :

```
 window.location.replace('/results/#'+ params);
```

but this won't reload the page with new params,
Im also trying to reload the page after :

```
 window.location.pathname === '/results/' && window.location.reload();
```

but this will reload the page with old parms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` hash won't cause a page reload since it represents a fragment of the current page. You can listen to `onhashchange` and do something at that time.